# Is there an efficient way to create an object and get immediately the autoincremented id of the newly created object in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to store a reference to database entries with a generic purpose in an extra table of an SQL Database.

My data model in SQLAlchemy looks like this:

```py
class Entity(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(10))

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


class Entry(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name= db.Column(db.String(10))

    entity_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('entity.id'))

    def __init__(self, name, entity_id):
        self.name = name
        self.entity_id = entity_id


class Thing(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name= db.Column(db.String(10))

    entity_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('entity.id'))

    def __init__(self, name, entity_id):
        self.name = name
        self.entity_id = entity_id
```

As soon as an **Entry** or a **Thing** is created, there should be a reference in **entity_id** to a newly created entry in **Entity**. For solving this i create an entity first, commit it, get then the id from the newly created entity and create the **Entry** or **Thing** with the grabbed id.

```py
# Create a new Entity object
entity = Entity(entity_title)

# Commit the entity
db.session.add(entity)
db.session.commit()

# Get the entity ID
entity_id = Entity.query.filter_by(name=entity_title).first().id

# Create a new Entry/Thing object
entry= Entry(name, entity_id)

# Commit the entry
db.session.add(task)
db.session.commit()
```

This way seems quite inefficient. Is there maybe another way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of dealing with foreign keys manually, [relationships](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html) serve this exact purpose of allowing you to deal with in-memory representations of objects and their relationships, without having to do `flush()`es in the correct order to figure out what foreign keys you should put where.

```
class Entry(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name= db.Column(db.String(10))

    entity_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('entity.id'))
    entity = relationship(Entity)

entry = Entry(name="foo", entity=Entry(name="foo"))
db.session.add(entry)
db.session.commit()
```

Notice how you don't have to deal with `entity_id` at all?

In your particular situation, you may also find [inheritance](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html) useful:

```
class Entity(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "entities"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(10))
    type = db.Column(db.Enum("entry", "thing"))

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_on": type,
    }

class Entry(Entity):
    __tablename__ = "entries"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('entity.id') primary_key=True)

class Thing(Entity):
    __tablename__ = "things"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('entity.id') primary_key=True)

entry = Entry(name="foo")  # automatically deals with the entities table
db.session.add(entry)
db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use session.flush()

```
entity = Entity(entity_title)

# Commit the entity
db.session.add(entity)
db.session.flush()
```

after that you may have id in `entity.id`
`session.flush()` only "create" an instance but it actualy didn't commit your session
In your case

```
# Create a new Entity object
entity = Entity(entity_title)

# Commit the entity
db.session.add(entity)
db.session.flush()

# Didn't need 
# Get the entity ID
# entity_id = Entity.query.filter_by(name=entity_title).first().id

# Create a new Entry/Thing object
entry= Entry(name, entity.id)

# Commit the entry
db.session.add(task)
db.session.commit()
```

Here docs
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.flush

Comment: Thanks! This does exactly what i wanted.